# Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I am getting an error on Magento on one of my web-forms:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /home/excalibur/public_html/includes/src/VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Fields.php
>   on line 577

This is the code:

```
    // check hidden field permission
    $types->setData('hidden', Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Hidden'));

    // add more field types
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_types', array('types' => $types));

    return $types->getData();

}

public function getComment()
{
    $comment = $this->getData('comment');
    return trim(preg_replace($this->tooltip_clean_regex, "", $comment));
}

public function getTooltip($option = false)
{
    $matches = array();
    $pattern = $this->tooltip_regex;
    $comment = $this->getData('comment');

    if ($option) {
        $pattern = $this->tooltip_option_regex;
        preg_match_all($pattern, $comment, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1]))
            foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $match) {
                if (trim($match) == trim($option))
                    return $matches[2][$i];
            }
        return false;
    }

    preg_match($pattern, $comment, $matches);

    if (!empty($matches[1]))
        return trim($matches[1]);

    return false;
}

public function getName()
{
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/general/use_translation')) {
        return Mage::helper('webforms')->__($this->getData('name'));
    }

    return $this->getData('name');
}

public function getSelectOptions($clean = true)
{
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    $options = explode("\n", $field_value['options']);
    $options = array_map('trim', $options);
    $select_options = array();
    foreach ($options as $o) {
        if ($this->getType() == 'select/contact') {
            if ($clean) {
                $contact = $this->getContactArray($o);
                $o = $contact['name'];
            }
        }
        $value = $this->getCheckedOptionValue($o);
        $label = $value;
        $matches = array();
        preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);


        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $value = trim($matches[1]);
            $label = preg_replace($this->val_regex, "", $label);
        }
        $select_options[$value] = trim($label);
    }
    return $select_options;
}

public function getResultsOptions()
{
    $query = $this->getResource()->getReadConnection()
        ->select('value')
        ->from($this->getResource()->getTable('webforms/results_values'), array('value'))
        ->where('field_id = ' . $this->getId())
        ->order('value asc')
        ->distinct();
    $results = $this->getResource()->getReadConnection()->fetchAll($query);
    $options = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $options[$result['value']] = $result['value'];
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getSizeTypes()
{
    $types = new Varien_Object(array(
        "standard" => Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Standard'),
        "wide" => Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Wide'),
    ));

    // add more size types
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_size_types', array('types' => $types));

    return $types->getData();

}

public function getAllowedExtensions()
{
    if ($this->getType() == 'image')
        return array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    if ($this->getType() == 'file') {
        $allowed_extensions = explode("\n", trim($this->getValue('allowed_extensions')));
        $allowed_extensions = array_map('trim', $allowed_extensions);
        $allowed_extensions = array_map('strtolower', $allowed_extensions);
        $filtered_result = array();
        foreach ($allowed_extensions as $ext) {
            if (strlen($ext) > 0) {
                $filtered_result[] = $ext;
            }
        }
        return $filtered_result;
    }
    return;
}

public function getRestrictedExtensions()
{
    return array('php', 'pl', 'py', 'jsp', 'asp', 'htm', 'html', 'js', 'sh', 'shtml', 'cgi', 'com', 'exe', 'bat', 'cmd', 'vbs', 'vbe', 'jse', 'wsf', 'wsh', 'psc1');
}

public function getStarsCount()
{
    //return default value
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    if (!empty($field_value['stars_max'])) {
        $value = $field_value['stars_max'];
        if ($value > 0) return $value;
    }
    return 5;
}

public function getStarsInit()
{
    //return default value
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    $value = 0;
    if (!empty($field_value['stars_init']))
        $value = $field_value['stars_init'];
    if ($value > 0) return $value;
    return ceil($this->getStarsCount() / 2);
}

public function getStarsOptions()
{
    $count = $this->getStarsCount();
    $options = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $options[$i] = $i;
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getDateType()
{
    $type = "medium";
    return $type;
}

public function getDateFormat()
{
    $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat($this->getDateType());
    if ($this->getType() == 'datetime') {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat($this->getDateType());
    }
    return $format;
}

public function getDateStrFormat()
{
    $str_format = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrftime($this->getDateFormat(), true, true);
    return $str_format;
}

public function getDbDateFormat()
{
    $format = "Y-m-d";
    if ($this->getType() == 'datetime') {
        $format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
    }
    return $format;
}

public function formatDate($value)
{
    if (strlen($value) > 0) {
        $format = $this->getDateStrFormat();
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
            $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format);
        }
        return strftime($format, strtotime($value));
    }
    return;
}

public function isCheckedOption($value)
{
    $customer_value = $this->getData('customer_value');
    if ($customer_value) {
        if (is_string($customer_value))
            $customer_values_array = explode("\n", $customer_value);
        elseif (is_array($customer_value))
            $customer_values_array = $customer_value;
        else return false;
        foreach ($customer_values_array as $val) {
            $realVal = $this->getRealCheckedOptionValue($value);
            if (trim($val) == $realVal) {
                return true;
            }
            $realVal = trim(preg_replace($this->contact_regex, '', $realVal));
            if (trim($val) == $realVal) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function isNullOption($value)
{
    if (substr($value, 0, 2) == '^^')
        return true;
    if (stristr($value, '{{null}}'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function isDisabledOption($value)
{
    if (stristr($value, '{{disabled}}'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function getCheckedOptionValue($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace($this->img_regex, "", $value);
    $value = str_replace('{{null}}', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('{{disabled}}', '', $value);

    if ($this->isNullOption($value) && substr($value, 0, 2) == '^^')
        return trim(substr($value, 2));
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return trim(substr($value, 1));
    return trim($value);
}

public function getRealCheckedOptionValue($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace($this->img_regex, "", $value);
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
        $value = trim($matches[1]);
    }

    if ($this->isNullOption($value))
        return trim(substr($value, 2));
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return trim(substr($value, 1));
    return trim($value);
}

public function getOptionsArray()
{
    $options = array();
    $field_value = $this->getValue('options');
    $values = explode("\n", $field_value);
    foreach ($values as $val) {
        $image_src = false;

        $matches = array();
        preg_match($this->img_regex, $val, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1])) {
            $image_src = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $matches[1];
        }

        if (strlen(trim($val)) > 0) {
            $value = $this->getCheckedOptionValue($val);
            $label = $value;

            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/general/use_translation')) $label = Mage::helper('webforms')->__($value);

            $matches = array();
            preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);
            if (isset($matches[1])) {
                $value = trim($matches[1]);
            }

            $options[] = array(
                'value' => @$this->getFilter()->filter($value),
                'label' => trim(@$this->getFilter()->filter($label)),
                'null' => $this->isNullOption($val),
                'checked' => $this->isCheckedOption($val),
                'disabled' => $this->isDisabledOption($val),
                'image_src' => $image_src,
            );
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getContactArray($value)
{
    preg_match('/(\w.+) <([^<]+?)>/', $value, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[2]))
        return array("name" => trim($matches[1]), "email" => trim($matches[2]));
    return array("name" => trim($value), "email" => "");
}

public function getContactValueById($id)
{
    $options = $this->getOptionsArray();
    if (!empty($options[$id]['value']))
        return $options[$id]['value'];
    return false;
}

public function getHiddenFieldValue()
{
    $result = $this->getData('result');
    $customer_value = $result ? $result->getData('field_' . $this->getId()) : false;
    if ($customer_value) return $customer_value;

    $field_value = $this->getValue();

    $filter = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor();
    $filter->setVariables(array(
        'product' => Mage::registry('product'),
        'category' => Mage::registry('category'),
        'customer' => Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer(),
        'core_session' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session'),
        'customer_session' => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'),
        'url' => Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),
    ));

    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_hidden_value', array('field' => $this, 'filter' => $filter));

    return trim($filter->filter($field_value['hidden']));
}

public function getFilter()
{
    $filter = new Varien_Filter_Template_Simple();

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()) {
        foreach ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getData() as $key => $value) {
            $filter->setData($key, $value);
            if ($key == 'street') {
                $streetArray = explode("\n", $value);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($streetArray); $i++) {
                    $filter->setData('street_' . ($i + 1), $streetArray[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $customer_data = $customer->getData();
    foreach ($customer_data as $key => $value) {
        $filter->setData($key, $value);
    }

    return $filter;
}

public function toHtml()
{
    $filter = $this->getFilter();

    // apply custom filter
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_tohtml_filter', array('filter' => $filter));

    $field_id = "field" . $this->getUid() . $this->getId();
    $field_name = "field[" . $this->getId() . "]";
    $field_value = @$filter->filter($this->getValue());
    if (is_array($field_value))
        $field_value = array_map('trim', $field_value);
    if (is_string($field_value))
        $field_value = trim($field_value);
    $result = $this->getData('result');

    $customer_value = $result ? $result->getData('field_' . $this->getId()) : false;

    // set values from URL parameter
    if ($this->getWebform()->getAcceptUrlParameters()) {
        $request_value = trim(strval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($this->getCode())));
        if ($request_value) $customer_value = $request_value;
    }

    $this->setData('customer_value', $customer_value);
    $field_type = $this->getType();
    $field_class = "input-text";
    $field_style = "";

    if ($field_type == 'file' || $field_type == 'image') {
        $field_class = "input-file";
    }
    if ($this->getRequired())
        $field_class .= " required-entry";
    if ($field_type == "email")
        $field_class .= " validate-email";
    if ($field_type == "number")
        $field_class .= " validate-number";

    if (!empty($field_value['number_min']) || (!empty($field_value['number_min']) && $field_value['number_min'] == '0')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-number-min-' . $this->getId();
    }
    if (!empty($field_value['number_max']) || (!empty($field_value['number_max']) && $field_value['number_max'] == '0')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-number-max-' . $this->getId();
    }

    if ($field_type == "url")
        $field_class .= " validate-url";
    if ($this->getCssClass()) {
        $field_class .= ' ' . $this->getCssClass();
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_min') || $this->getData('validate_length_max')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-length';
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_min')) {
        $field_class .= ' minimum-length-' . $this->getData('validate_length_min');
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_max')) {
        $field_class .= ' maximum-length-' . $this->getData('validate_length_max');
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_regex')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-' . $this->getId();
    }
    if ($this->getCssStyle()) {
        $field_style = $this->getCssStyle();
    }
    $tinyMCE = false;
    $showTime = false;
    $calendar = false;
    $config = array(
        'field' => $this,
        'field_id' => $field_id,
        'field_name' => $field_name,
        'field_class' => $field_class,
        'field_style' => $field_style,
        'webform_id' => $this->getWebformId(),
        'result' => $result,
        'show_time' => 'false',
        'customer_value' => $customer_value,
        'template' => 'webforms/fields/text.phtml'
    );
    if ($customer_value)
        $config['field_value'] = $customer_value;
    $block_type = 'core/template';
    switch ($field_type) {
        case 'text':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['text']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['text'];
            break;
        case 'email':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['text_email']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['text_email'];
            break;
        case 'number':
            empty($field_value['number_min']) ? $config['min'] = false : $config['min'] = $field_value['number_min'];
            empty($field_value['number_max']) ? $config['max'] = false : $config['max'] = $field_value['number_max'];
            if (!empty($field_value['number_min'])) $field_value['number_min'] == '0' ? $config['min'] = 0 : $config['min'] = $field_value['number_min'];
            if (!empty($field_value['number_max'])) $field_value['number_max'] == '0' ? $config['max'] = 0 : $config['max'] = $field_value['number_max'];
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/number.phtml';
            break;
        case 'password':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/password.phtml';
            break;
        case 'autocomplete':
            $config['choices'] = explode("\n", $this->getValue('autocomplete_choices'));
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/auto-complete.phtml';
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['textarea']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['textarea'];
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/textarea.phtml';
            break;
        case 'wysiwyg':
            $tinyMCE = true;
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/wysiwyg.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/contact':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_contact.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/radio':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_radio.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/checkbox':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_checkbox.phtml';
            break;
        case 'subscribe':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            !empty($field_value['newsletter_label']) ? $config['label'] = $field_value['newsletter_label'] : $config['label'] = false;
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/subscribe.phtml';
            break;
        case 'stars':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/stars.phtml';
            break;
        case 'image':
        case 'file':
            $config['field_id'] = 'file_' . $this->getId();
            $config['field_name'] = $config['field_id'];
            $config['files'] = false;
            if($result->getId()){
                $config['files'] = Mage::getModel('webforms/files')->getCollection()->addFilter('result_id', $result->getId())->addFilter('field_id', $this->getId());
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/file.phtml';
            break;
        case 'html':
            $processor = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $config['field_value'] = $processor->filter($this->getValue('html'));
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/html.phtml';
            break;
        case 'datetime':
            $config['show_time'] = 'true';
            $showTime = true;
        case 'date':
        case 'datetime':
            $calendar = true;
            if ($customer_value) {
                // format customer value
                $config['customer_value'] = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($customer_value, $this->getDateType(), $showTime);
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/date.phtml';
            break;
        case 'date/dob':
            $block_type = 'customer/widget_dob';
            if ($customer_value) {
                // set dob
                $config['time'] = strtotime($customer_value);
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/dob.phtml';
            break;
        case 'hidden':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/hidden.phtml';
            break;
        case 'country':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/country.phtml';
            break;
        default:
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/text.phtml';
            break;
    }
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();

    $html = $layout->createBlock($block_type, $field_name, $config)->setTemplate($config['template'])->toHtml();

    if ($this->getData('validate_regex')) {
        $flags = array();

        $regexp = trim($this->getData('validate_regex'));

        preg_match('/\/([igmy]{1,4})$/', $regexp, $flags);

        // set regex flags
        if (!empty($flags[1])) {
            $flags = $flags[1];
            $regexp = substr($regexp, 0, strlen($regexp) - strlen($flags));
        } else {
            $flags = '';
        }

        if (substr($regexp, 0, 1) == '/' && substr($regexp, strlen($regexp) - 1, strlen($regexp)) == '/')
            $regexp = substr($regexp, 1, -1);
        $regexp = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $regexp);

        $validate_message = trim(str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $this->getData('validate_message')));

        // custom regex validation
        $validate_script = "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v,elm){
            var r = new RegExp('{$regexp}','{$flags}');
            var isValid = Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || r.test(v);";
        if ($this->getType() == 'select/checkbox' || $this->getType() == 'select/radio') {
            $validate_script .= "
                isValid = false;
                var inputs = $$('input[name=\"' + elm.name.replace(/([\\\"])/g, '\\$1') + '\"]');
                for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
                    if((inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' || inputs[i].type == 'radio') && inputs[i].checked == true && r.test(inputs[i].value)) {
                        isValid = true;
                    }

                    if(Validation.isOnChange && (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' || inputs[i].type == 'radio')) {
                        Validation.reset(inputs[i]);
                    }
                }
            ";
        }
        $validate_script .= "
            return isValid;
        })</script>";

        $html .= $validate_script;
    }

    if ($field_type == 'number') {
        if (!empty($field_value['number_min']) || (!empty($field_value['number_min']) && $field_value['number_min'] == '0')) {
            $validate_message = Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Minimum value is %s', $field_value['number_min']);
            $html .= "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-number-min-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v){return v >= {$field_value['number_min']};})</script>";
        }
        if (!empty($field_value['number_max']) || (!empty($field_value['number_max']) && $field_value['number_max'] == '0')) {
            $validate_message = Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Maximum value is %s', $field_value['number_max']);
            $html .= "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-number-max-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v){return v <= {$field_value['number_max']};})</script>";
        }
    }


    // activate tinyMCE
    if ($tinyMCE && !Mage::registry('tinyMCE')) {
        Mage::register('tinyMCE', true);
        $tiny_mce = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'tinyMCE', array('template' => 'webforms/scripts/tiny_mce.phtml'));
        $html .= $tiny_mce->toHtml();
    }

    // activate calendar
    if ($calendar && !Mage::registry('calendar')) {
        Mage::register('calendar', true);
        $calendar_block = $layout->createBlock('core/html_calendar', 'calendar_block', array
        (
            'as' => 'calendar',
            'template' => 'page/js/calendar.phtml'
        ));
        $html .= $calendar_block->toHtml();
    }

    // apply custom field type
    $html_object = new Varien_Object(array('html' => $html));
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_tohtml_html', array('field' => $this, 'html_object' => $html_object));

    return $html_object->getHtml();
}

public function duplicate()
{
    // duplicate field
    $field = Mage::getModel('webforms/fields')
        ->setData($this->getData())
        ->setId(null)
        ->setName($this->getName() . ' ' . Mage::helper('webforms')->__('(new copy)'))
        ->setIsActive(false)
        ->setCreatedTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->setUpdateTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->save();

    // duplicate store data
    $stores = Mage::getModel('webforms/store')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('entity_id', $this->getId())
        ->addFilter('entity_type', $this->getEntityType());

    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $duplicate = Mage::getModel('webforms/store')
            ->setData($store->getData())
            ->setId(null)
            ->setEntityId($field->getId())
            ->save();
    }

    return $field;
}

public function getLogic()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('webforms/logic')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->getCollection()->addFilter('field_id', $this->getId());
    return $collection;
}

public function getLogicTargetOptionsArray()
{
    $options = array();
    $webform = Mage::getModel('webforms/webforms')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->load($this->getWebformId());
    $fields_to_fieldsets = $webform->getFieldsToFieldsets(true);

    foreach ($fields_to_fieldsets as $fieldset_id => $fieldset) {
        $field_options = array();
        foreach ($fieldset['fields'] as $field) {
            if ($field->getId() != $this->getId() && $field->getType() != 'hidden')
                $field_options[] = array('value' => 'field_' . $field->getId(), 'label' => $field->getName());
        }

        if ($fieldset_id) {
            if ($this->getFieldsetId() != $fieldset_id)
                $options[] = array('value' => 'fieldset_' . $fieldset_id, 'label' => $fieldset['name'] . ' [' . Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Field Set') . ']');
            if (count($field_options)) {
                $options[] = array('value' => $field_options, 'label' => $fieldset['name']);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($field_options as $opt) {
                $options[] = $opt;
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}

public function prepareResultValue($value)
{

    switch ($this->getType()) {
        case 'select/contact':
            $contact = $this->getContactArray($value);
            if (!empty($contact["name"])) $value = $contact["name"];
            break;
    }

    $valueObj = new Varien_Object(array('value' => $value));

    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_prepare_result_value', array('field' => $this, 'value' => $valueObj));

    return $valueObj->getValue();
}

public function getWebform()
{
    if (!$this->_webform) {
        /** @var VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Webforms $webform */
        $webform = Mage::getModel('webforms/webforms')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->load($this->getWebformId());
        $this->_webform = $webform;
    }
    return $this->_webform;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add more code lines, I don't see your `$result` object.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of more code, the odds are good that your `$result` object is null when you try and call `getId()` on it.

To fix this use this:

```
if($result) {
   $resultId = $result->getId();
}

if ($resultId) {
   .......
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just posted more of the code. I attempted to add the piece of code you suggested but now it just hangs and does not submit.

Comment: Looking over this a little more, there might be a required field in the admin set up of this code that is missing. Has this extension worked for you in the past? The basic problem is that the value `$result` is not getting set when it calls `$result = $this->getData('result');` in the toHtml() method. The why is a little more tricky to figure out.

Comment: Yeah it has worked for me before. This is an error I am getting from adding and image upload field on the admin to one of my forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // check hidden field permission
    $types->setData('hidden', Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Hidden'));

    // add more field types
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_types', array('types' => $types));

    return $types->getData();

}

public function getComment()
{
    $comment = $this->getData('comment');
    return trim(preg_replace($this->tooltip_clean_regex, "", $comment));
}

public function getTooltip($option = false)
{
    $matches = array();
    $pattern = $this->tooltip_regex;
    $comment = $this->getData('comment');

    if ($option) {
        $pattern = $this->tooltip_option_regex;
        preg_match_all($pattern, $comment, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1]))
            foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $match) {
                if (trim($match) == trim($option))
                    return $matches[2][$i];
            }
        return false;
    }

    preg_match($pattern, $comment, $matches);

    if (!empty($matches[1]))
        return trim($matches[1]);

    return false;
}

public function getName()
{
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/general/use_translation')) {
        return Mage::helper('webforms')->__($this->getData('name'));
    }

    return $this->getData('name');
}

public function getSelectOptions($clean = true)
{
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    $options = explode("\n", $field_value['options']);
    $options = array_map('trim', $options);
    $select_options = array();
    foreach ($options as $o) {
        if ($this->getType() == 'select/contact') {
            if ($clean) {
                $contact = $this->getContactArray($o);
                $o = $contact['name'];
            }
        }
        $value = $this->getCheckedOptionValue($o);
        $label = $value;
        $matches = array();
        preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);


        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $value = trim($matches[1]);
            $label = preg_replace($this->val_regex, "", $label);
        }
        $select_options[$value] = trim($label);
    }
    return $select_options;
}

public function getResultsOptions()
{
    $query = $this->getResource()->getReadConnection()
        ->select('value')
        ->from($this->getResource()->getTable('webforms/results_values'), array('value'))
        ->where('field_id = ' . $this->getId())
        ->order('value asc')
        ->distinct();
    $results = $this->getResource()->getReadConnection()->fetchAll($query);
    $options = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $options[$result['value']] = $result['value'];
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getSizeTypes()
{
    $types = new Varien_Object(array(
        "standard" => Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Standard'),
        "wide" => Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Wide'),
    ));

    // add more size types
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_size_types', array('types' => $types));

    return $types->getData();

}

public function getAllowedExtensions()
{
    if ($this->getType() == 'image')
        return array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    if ($this->getType() == 'file') {
        $allowed_extensions = explode("\n", trim($this->getValue('allowed_extensions')));
        $allowed_extensions = array_map('trim', $allowed_extensions);
        $allowed_extensions = array_map('strtolower', $allowed_extensions);
        $filtered_result = array();
        foreach ($allowed_extensions as $ext) {
            if (strlen($ext) > 0) {
                $filtered_result[] = $ext;
            }
        }
        return $filtered_result;
    }
    return;
}

public function getRestrictedExtensions()
{
    return array('php', 'pl', 'py', 'jsp', 'asp', 'htm', 'html', 'js', 'sh', 'shtml', 'cgi', 'com', 'exe', 'bat', 'cmd', 'vbs', 'vbe', 'jse', 'wsf', 'wsh', 'psc1');
}

public function getStarsCount()
{
    //return default value
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    if (!empty($field_value['stars_max'])) {
        $value = $field_value['stars_max'];
        if ($value > 0) return $value;
    }
    return 5;
}

public function getStarsInit()
{
    //return default value
    $field_value = $this->getValue();
    $value = 0;
    if (!empty($field_value['stars_init']))
        $value = $field_value['stars_init'];
    if ($value > 0) return $value;
    return ceil($this->getStarsCount() / 2);
}

public function getStarsOptions()
{
    $count = $this->getStarsCount();
    $options = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $options[$i] = $i;
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getDateType()
{
    $type = "medium";
    return $type;
}

public function getDateFormat()
{
    $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat($this->getDateType());
    if ($this->getType() == 'datetime') {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat($this->getDateType());
    }
    return $format;
}

public function getDateStrFormat()
{
    $str_format = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrftime($this->getDateFormat(), true, true);
    return $str_format;
}

public function getDbDateFormat()
{
    $format = "Y-m-d";
    if ($this->getType() == 'datetime') {
        $format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
    }
    return $format;
}

public function formatDate($value)
{
    if (strlen($value) > 0) {
        $format = $this->getDateStrFormat();
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
            $format = preg_replace('#(?<!%)((?:%%)*)%e#', '\1%#d', $format);
        }
        return strftime($format, strtotime($value));
    }
    return;
}

public function isCheckedOption($value)
{
    $customer_value = $this->getData('customer_value');
    if ($customer_value) {
        if (is_string($customer_value))
            $customer_values_array = explode("\n", $customer_value);
        elseif (is_array($customer_value))
            $customer_values_array = $customer_value;
        else return false;
        foreach ($customer_values_array as $val) {
            $realVal = $this->getRealCheckedOptionValue($value);
            if (trim($val) == $realVal) {
                return true;
            }
            $realVal = trim(preg_replace($this->contact_regex, '', $realVal));
            if (trim($val) == $realVal) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function isNullOption($value)
{
    if (substr($value, 0, 2) == '^^')
        return true;
    if (stristr($value, '{{null}}'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function isDisabledOption($value)
{
    if (stristr($value, '{{disabled}}'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public function getCheckedOptionValue($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace($this->img_regex, "", $value);
    $value = str_replace('{{null}}', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('{{disabled}}', '', $value);

    if ($this->isNullOption($value) && substr($value, 0, 2) == '^^')
        return trim(substr($value, 2));
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return trim(substr($value, 1));
    return trim($value);
}

public function getRealCheckedOptionValue($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace($this->img_regex, "", $value);
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
        $value = trim($matches[1]);
    }

    if ($this->isNullOption($value))
        return trim(substr($value, 2));
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '^')
        return trim(substr($value, 1));
    return trim($value);
}

public function getOptionsArray()
{
    $options = array();
    $field_value = $this->getValue('options');
    $values = explode("\n", $field_value);
    foreach ($values as $val) {
        $image_src = false;

        $matches = array();
        preg_match($this->img_regex, $val, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1])) {
            $image_src = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $matches[1];
        }

        if (strlen(trim($val)) > 0) {
            $value = $this->getCheckedOptionValue($val);
            $label = $value;

            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/general/use_translation')) $label = Mage::helper('webforms')->__($value);

            $matches = array();
            preg_match($this->val_regex, $value, $matches);
            if (isset($matches[1])) {
                $value = trim($matches[1]);
            }

            $options[] = array(
                'value' => @$this->getFilter()->filter($value),
                'label' => trim(@$this->getFilter()->filter($label)),
                'null' => $this->isNullOption($val),
                'checked' => $this->isCheckedOption($val),
                'disabled' => $this->isDisabledOption($val),
                'image_src' => $image_src,
            );
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

public function getContactArray($value)
{
    preg_match('/(\w.+) <([^<]+?)>/', $value, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1]) && !empty($matches[2]))
        return array("name" => trim($matches[1]), "email" => trim($matches[2]));
    return array("name" => trim($value), "email" => "");
}

public function getContactValueById($id)
{
    $options = $this->getOptionsArray();
    if (!empty($options[$id]['value']))
        return $options[$id]['value'];
    return false;
}

public function getHiddenFieldValue()
{
    $result = $this->getData('result');
    $customer_value = $result ? $result->getData('field_' . $this->getId()) : false;
    if ($customer_value) return $customer_value;

    $field_value = $this->getValue();

    $filter = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor();
    $filter->setVariables(array(
        'product' => Mage::registry('product'),
        'category' => Mage::registry('category'),
        'customer' => Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer(),
        'core_session' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session'),
        'customer_session' => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'),
        'url' => Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),
    ));

    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_hidden_value', array('field' => $this, 'filter' => $filter));

    return trim($filter->filter($field_value['hidden']));
}

public function getFilter()
{
    $filter = new Varien_Filter_Template_Simple();

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()) {
        foreach ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getData() as $key => $value) {
            $filter->setData($key, $value);
            if ($key == 'street') {
                $streetArray = explode("\n", $value);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($streetArray); $i++) {
                    $filter->setData('street_' . ($i + 1), $streetArray[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $customer_data = $customer->getData();
    foreach ($customer_data as $key => $value) {
        $filter->setData($key, $value);
    }

    return $filter;
}

public function toHtml()
{
    $filter = $this->getFilter();

    // apply custom filter
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_tohtml_filter', array('filter' => $filter));

    $field_id = "field" . $this->getUid() . $this->getId();
    $field_name = "field[" . $this->getId() . "]";
    $field_value = @$filter->filter($this->getValue());
    if (is_array($field_value))
        $field_value = array_map('trim', $field_value);
    if (is_string($field_value))
        $field_value = trim($field_value);
    $result = $this->getData('result');

    $customer_value = $result ? $result->getData('field_' . $this->getId()) : false;

    // set values from URL parameter
    if ($this->getWebform()->getAcceptUrlParameters()) {
        $request_value = trim(strval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam($this->getCode())));
        if ($request_value) $customer_value = $request_value;
    }

    $this->setData('customer_value', $customer_value);
    $field_type = $this->getType();
    $field_class = "input-text";
    $field_style = "";

    if ($field_type == 'file' || $field_type == 'image') {
        $field_class = "input-file";
    }
    if ($this->getRequired())
        $field_class .= " required-entry";
    if ($field_type == "email")
        $field_class .= " validate-email";
    if ($field_type == "number")
        $field_class .= " validate-number";

    if (!empty($field_value['number_min']) || (!empty($field_value['number_min']) && $field_value['number_min'] == '0')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-number-min-' . $this->getId();
    }
    if (!empty($field_value['number_max']) || (!empty($field_value['number_max']) && $field_value['number_max'] == '0')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-number-max-' . $this->getId();
    }

    if ($field_type == "url")
        $field_class .= " validate-url";
    if ($this->getCssClass()) {
        $field_class .= ' ' . $this->getCssClass();
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_min') || $this->getData('validate_length_max')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-length';
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_min')) {
        $field_class .= ' minimum-length-' . $this->getData('validate_length_min');
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_length_max')) {
        $field_class .= ' maximum-length-' . $this->getData('validate_length_max');
    }
    if ($this->getData('validate_regex')) {
        $field_class .= ' validate-field-' . $this->getId();
    }
    if ($this->getCssStyle()) {
        $field_style = $this->getCssStyle();
    }
    $tinyMCE = false;
    $showTime = false;
    $calendar = false;
    $config = array(
        'field' => $this,
        'field_id' => $field_id,
        'field_name' => $field_name,
        'field_class' => $field_class,
        'field_style' => $field_style,
        'webform_id' => $this->getWebformId(),
        'result' => $result,
        'show_time' => 'false',
        'customer_value' => $customer_value,
        'template' => 'webforms/fields/text.phtml'
    );
    if ($customer_value)
        $config['field_value'] = $customer_value;
    $block_type = 'core/template';
    switch ($field_type) {
        case 'text':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['text']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['text'];
            break;
        case 'email':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['text_email']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['text_email'];
            break;
        case 'number':
            empty($field_value['number_min']) ? $config['min'] = false : $config['min'] = $field_value['number_min'];
            empty($field_value['number_max']) ? $config['max'] = false : $config['max'] = $field_value['number_max'];
            if (!empty($field_value['number_min'])) $field_value['number_min'] == '0' ? $config['min'] = 0 : $config['min'] = $field_value['number_min'];
            if (!empty($field_value['number_max'])) $field_value['number_max'] == '0' ? $config['max'] = 0 : $config['max'] = $field_value['number_max'];
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/number.phtml';
            break;
        case 'password':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/password.phtml';
            break;
        case 'autocomplete':
            $config['choices'] = explode("\n", $this->getValue('autocomplete_choices'));
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/auto-complete.phtml';
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            if (!$customer_value) empty($field_value['textarea']) ? $config['field_value'] = '' : $config['field_value'] = $field_value['textarea'];
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/textarea.phtml';
            break;
        case 'wysiwyg':
            $tinyMCE = true;
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/wysiwyg.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/contact':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_contact.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/radio':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_radio.phtml';
            break;
        case 'select/checkbox':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/select_checkbox.phtml';
            break;
        case 'subscribe':
            $config['field_class'] = $this->getCssClass();
            !empty($field_value['newsletter_label']) ? $config['label'] = $field_value['newsletter_label'] : $config['label'] = false;
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/subscribe.phtml';
            break;
        case 'stars':
            $config['field_options'] = $this->getOptionsArray();
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/stars.phtml';
            break;
        case 'image':
        case 'file':
            $config['field_id'] = 'file_' . $this->getId();
            $config['field_name'] = $config['field_id'];
            $config['files'] = false;
            if($result->getId()){
                $config['files'] = Mage::getModel('webforms/files')->getCollection()->addFilter('result_id', $result->getId())->addFilter('field_id', $this->getId());
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/file.phtml';
            break;
        case 'html':
            $processor = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $config['field_value'] = $processor->filter($this->getValue('html'));
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/html.phtml';
            break;
        case 'datetime':
            $config['show_time'] = 'true';
            $showTime = true;
        case 'date':
        case 'datetime':
            $calendar = true;
            if ($customer_value) {
                // format customer value
                $config['customer_value'] = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($customer_value, $this->getDateType(), $showTime);
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/date.phtml';
            break;
        case 'date/dob':
            $block_type = 'customer/widget_dob';
            if ($customer_value) {
                // set dob
                $config['time'] = strtotime($customer_value);
            }
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/dob.phtml';
            break;
        case 'hidden':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/hidden.phtml';
            break;
        case 'country':
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/country.phtml';
            break;
        default:
            $config['template'] = 'webforms/fields/text.phtml';
            break;
    }
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();

    $html = $layout->createBlock($block_type, $field_name, $config)->setTemplate($config['template'])->toHtml();

    if ($this->getData('validate_regex')) {
        $flags = array();

        $regexp = trim($this->getData('validate_regex'));

        preg_match('/\/([igmy]{1,4})$/', $regexp, $flags);

        // set regex flags
        if (!empty($flags[1])) {
            $flags = $flags[1];
            $regexp = substr($regexp, 0, strlen($regexp) - strlen($flags));
        } else {
            $flags = '';
        }

        if (substr($regexp, 0, 1) == '/' && substr($regexp, strlen($regexp) - 1, strlen($regexp)) == '/')
            $regexp = substr($regexp, 1, -1);
        $regexp = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $regexp);

        $validate_message = trim(str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $this->getData('validate_message')));

        // custom regex validation
        $validate_script = "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v,elm){
            var r = new RegExp('{$regexp}','{$flags}');
            var isValid = Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || r.test(v);";
        if ($this->getType() == 'select/checkbox' || $this->getType() == 'select/radio') {
            $validate_script .= "
                isValid = false;
                var inputs = $$('input[name=\"' + elm.name.replace(/([\\\"])/g, '\\$1') + '\"]');
                for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
                    if((inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' || inputs[i].type == 'radio') && inputs[i].checked == true && r.test(inputs[i].value)) {
                        isValid = true;
                    }

                    if(Validation.isOnChange && (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' || inputs[i].type == 'radio')) {
                        Validation.reset(inputs[i]);
                    }
                }
            ";
        }
        $validate_script .= "
            return isValid;
        })</script>";

        $html .= $validate_script;
    }

    if ($field_type == 'number') {
        if (!empty($field_value['number_min']) || (!empty($field_value['number_min']) && $field_value['number_min'] == '0')) {
            $validate_message = Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Minimum value is %s', $field_value['number_min']);
            $html .= "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-number-min-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v){return v >= {$field_value['number_min']};})</script>";
        }
        if (!empty($field_value['number_max']) || (!empty($field_value['number_max']) && $field_value['number_max'] == '0')) {
            $validate_message = Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Maximum value is %s', $field_value['number_max']);
            $html .= "<script>Validation.add('validate-field-number-max-{$this->getId()}','{$validate_message}',function(v){return v <= {$field_value['number_max']};})</script>";
        }
    }


    // activate tinyMCE
    if ($tinyMCE && !Mage::registry('tinyMCE')) {
        Mage::register('tinyMCE', true);
        $tiny_mce = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'tinyMCE', array('template' => 'webforms/scripts/tiny_mce.phtml'));
        $html .= $tiny_mce->toHtml();
    }

    // activate calendar
    if ($calendar && !Mage::registry('calendar')) {
        Mage::register('calendar', true);
        $calendar_block = $layout->createBlock('core/html_calendar', 'calendar_block', array
        (
            'as' => 'calendar',
            'template' => 'page/js/calendar.phtml'
        ));
        $html .= $calendar_block->toHtml();
    }

    // apply custom field type
    $html_object = new Varien_Object(array('html' => $html));
    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_tohtml_html', array('field' => $this, 'html_object' => $html_object));

    return $html_object->getHtml();
}

public function duplicate()
{
    // duplicate field
    $field = Mage::getModel('webforms/fields')
        ->setData($this->getData())
        ->setId(null)
        ->setName($this->getName() . ' ' . Mage::helper('webforms')->__('(new copy)'))
        ->setIsActive(false)
        ->setCreatedTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->setUpdateTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->save();

    // duplicate store data
    $stores = Mage::getModel('webforms/store')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('entity_id', $this->getId())
        ->addFilter('entity_type', $this->getEntityType());

    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $duplicate = Mage::getModel('webforms/store')
            ->setData($store->getData())
            ->setId(null)
            ->setEntityId($field->getId())
            ->save();
    }

    return $field;
}

public function getLogic()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('webforms/logic')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->getCollection()->addFilter('field_id', $this->getId());
    return $collection;
}

public function getLogicTargetOptionsArray()
{
    $options = array();
    $webform = Mage::getModel('webforms/webforms')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->load($this->getWebformId());
    $fields_to_fieldsets = $webform->getFieldsToFieldsets(true);

    foreach ($fields_to_fieldsets as $fieldset_id => $fieldset) {
        $field_options = array();
        foreach ($fieldset['fields'] as $field) {
            if ($field->getId() != $this->getId() && $field->getType() != 'hidden')
                $field_options[] = array('value' => 'field_' . $field->getId(), 'label' => $field->getName());
        }

        if ($fieldset_id) {
            if ($this->getFieldsetId() != $fieldset_id)
                $options[] = array('value' => 'fieldset_' . $fieldset_id, 'label' => $fieldset['name'] . ' [' . Mage::helper('webforms')->__('Field Set') . ']');
            if (count($field_options)) {
                $options[] = array('value' => $field_options, 'label' => $fieldset['name']);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($field_options as $opt) {
                $options[] = $opt;
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}

public function prepareResultValue($value)
{

    switch ($this->getType()) {
        case 'select/contact':
            $contact = $this->getContactArray($value);
            if (!empty($contact["name"])) $value = $contact["name"];
            break;
    }

    $valueObj = new Varien_Object(array('value' => $value));

    Mage::dispatchEvent('webforms_fields_prepare_result_value', array('field' => $this, 'value' => $valueObj));

    return $valueObj->getValue();
}

public function getWebform()
{
    if (!$this->_webform) {
        /** @var VladimirPopov_WebForms_Model_Webforms $webform */
        $webform = Mage::getModel('webforms/webforms')->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())->load($this->getWebformId());
        $this->_webform = $webform;
    }
    return $this->_webform;
}
```

}